# Module RCTEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling receiveTouches)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When i try to run the app after some changes i get this error.
What i'm doing wrong ?

> Module RCTEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling
>   receiveTouches)
>   __callFunction
>       C:\Users\Andrea Zani\Documents\WORK\weatherApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:295:6
>   
>       C:\Users\Andrea Zani\Documents\WORK\weatherApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:26
>   __guard
>       C:\Users\Andrea Zani\Documents\WORK\weatherApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:269:6
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       C:\Users\Andrea Zani\Documents\WORK\weatherApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:107:17

and here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react-native'

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Animated,
    ScrollView,
} from 'react-native'

import fetchWeather from './app/api/api'
import weatherIcon from './app/utils/icons'

class WeatherAppNative extends React.Component {

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            city: 'Bucuresti',
            country: 'Romania',
            weatherType: 'Clear',
            temperature: 21,
            searchedCity: 'Bucuresti',
            val: new Animated.Value(0),
            currentColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
            nextColor: this._randomColor(),
            icon: weatherIcon()
        }
    }

    getWeather() {
        fetchWeather(this.state.searchedCity).then((response) => {
            let weatherList = response.list[0]

            // Store nextColor, since we'd like to start next time with it.
            var current = this.state.nextColor

            // Reset animation
            this.state.val.setValue(0)

            this.setState({
                temperature: weatherList.main.temp,
                city: weatherList.name,
                country: weatherList.sys.country,
                weatherType: weatherList.weather[0].main,
                currentColor: current,
                nextColor: this._randomColor(),
                icon: weatherIcon(weatherList.weather[0].icon)
            })

        })
    }


    render() {
        var backgroundColor = this.state.val.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [
                this.state.currentColor,
                this.state.nextColor
            ],
        })


        // Start the animation
        Animated.spring(this.state.val, {
            tension: 1,
            friction: 20,
            toValue: 1
        }).start()


        return (
            <Animated.View style={{
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'stretch',
                justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{marginBottom: this.state.keyboardSpace}}>
                    <View style={[styles.animatedContainer]}>
                        <Text style={styles.icon}>
                            {this.state.icon}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.temperature}>
                            {Math.round(this.state.temperature) + '°C'}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.location}>
                            {this.state.city}, {this.state.country}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.weatherType}>
                            {this.state.weatherType}
                        </Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input}
                            onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                            onSubmitEditing={this.getWeather}
                            clearButtonMode={'always'}
                            clearTextOnFocus={true}
                            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
                            returnKeyType={'search'}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }


    onChangeText(searchedCity) {
        this.setState({
            searchedCity: searchedCity
        })
    }

    _randomColor() {
        var colors = [0, 1, 2].map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 255))

        return 'rgba(' + colors.join(',') + ',0.6)'
    }
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    animatedContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    temperature: {
        fontSize: 62,
        fontWeight: '100',
        margin: 0
    },
    location: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: '100',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    weatherType: {
        fontSize: 34,
        fontWeight: '500'
    },
    input: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#666',
        height: 40,
        marginVertical: 20,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
    icon: {
        fontFamily: 'WeatherIcons-Regular',
        fontSize: 130,
        padding: 0
    }
})

export default WeatherAppNative
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `React` like this: `import React from 'react'`.

Your code snippet had a few other issues relating to scope.

Here is a working snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Animated } from "react-native";

import fetchWeather from "./app/api/api";
import weatherIcon from "./app/utils/icons";

function randomColor() {
  const colors = [0, 1, 2].map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 255));
  return "rgba(" + colors.join(",") + ",0.6)";
}

export default class WeatherAppNative extends Component {
  state = {
    city: "Bucuresti",
    country: "Romania",
    weatherType: "Clear",
    temperature: 21,
    searchedCity: "Bucuresti",
    val: new Animated.Value(0),
    currentColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
    nextColor: randomColor(),
    icon: weatherIcon()
  };

  getWeather = async () => {
    const { nextColor, searchedCity, val } = this.state;
    const response = await fetchWeather(searchedCity);

    let weatherList = response.list[0];

    // Store nextColor, since we'd like to start next time with it.
    var current = nextColor;

    // Reset animation
    val.setValue(0);

    this.setState({
      temperature: weatherList.main.temp,
      city: weatherList.name,
      country: weatherList.sys.country,
      weatherType: weatherList.weather[0].main,
      currentColor: current,
      nextColor: randomColor(),
      icon: weatherIcon(weatherList.weather[0].icon)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const backgroundColor = this.state.val.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [this.state.currentColor, this.state.nextColor]
    });

    // Start the animation
    Animated.spring(this.state.val, {
      tension: 1,
      friction: 20,
      toValue: 1
    }).start();

    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          backgroundColor,
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: "stretch",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ marginBottom: this.state.keyboardSpace }}>
          <View style={[styles.animatedContainer]}>
            <Text style={styles.icon}>{this.state.icon}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.temperature}>
              {Math.round(this.state.temperature) + "°C"}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.location}>
              {this.state.city}, {this.state.country}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.weatherType}>{this.state.weatherType}</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
              onSubmitEditing={this.getWeather}
              clearButtonMode={"always"}
              clearTextOnFocus={true}
              enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
              returnKeyType={"search"}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }

  onChangeText = searchedCity =>
    this.setState({
      searchedCity: searchedCity
    });
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  animatedContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  temperature: {
    fontSize: 62,
    fontWeight: "100",
    margin: 0
  },
  location: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "100",
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  weatherType: {
    fontSize: 34,
    fontWeight: "500"
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#666",
    height: 40,
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  icon: {
    fontFamily: "WeatherIcons-Regular",
    fontSize: 130,
    padding: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me to fix the default Bowser project on ignite-cli version 2.2.3

Comment: This didn't work for me, either, my imports are `import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, TextInput, Animated, NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter} from 'react-native'
import MenuDrawer from 'react-native-side-drawer'` slightly different module detail but same error. Looked everwhere else for solution, now blocked.

Comment: I know it probably sounds stupid, but does need to add some Java code into the app as per: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to kill the node process `pkill node` and re-run the build  `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

THis mostly happens when the emulator is outdated, just update your cli (react-native or expo) then run react-native run android or after lunching expo hit a then it'll ask to update your emulator